# Spring JMS acknowledgement behavior with TIBCO EMS EXPLICIT_CLIENT_DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, tibco-ems

I am using Spring JMS with TIBCO EMS queue/topic for my spring boot application. The TIBCO EMS queue is setup with EXPLICIT_CLIENT_DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE. In my code, I am not setting the acknowledgment mode, so I assume spring will take it s default AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE. The behavior I notice in my listener onMessage method is, if the application successfully process the message, no redelivery of the same message And if the application throws a RuntimeException, there is a redelivery of the same message. The code is also with setSessionTransacted to true with DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory. In this scenario, is the spring actually acknowledging the message on my behalf or do the code need to set the message.acknowledge().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the javadocs for `Session`. `Auto` means the provider library automatically acks the message when `consumer.receive()` returns it, or the `consumer.messsageListener()` exits.

With a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, your listener is called directly by the provider's Consumer so messages won't be auto-ack'd until your listener exits normally.

The `DirectMessageListenerContainer` calls `receive()` instead and calls your listener on its own thread. Hence we need transactions to roll back the ack after an exception is thrown.

Comment: I am using 'DefaultMessageListenerContainer'. In the javadoc I can see it is mentioned as below
"Note that for the default "AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" mode, this container applies automatic message acknowledgment before listener execution, with no redelivery in case of an exception."
But the behavior I am seeing, as I mentioned in the question, is different from what mentioned in the javadoc

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; in your question you said you are using the DMLC and `setSessionTransacted=true`; that will cause redelivery if the listener throws an exception (which is what you say is happening). The message is ack'd within a transaction and the transaction is rolled back, hence the ack is rolled back too and the message re-queued.

Comment: what I was telling is the javadoc is telling "container applies automatic message acknowledgment 'before' listener execution," But for me the behavior is after the execution. The same which you told, but javadoc is telling it is before. That is what my confusion

Comment: The javadoc is correct; the message is indeed acknowledged before calling the listener (before `receive()` returns). It's just that, because the listener throws an exception, the transaction is rolled back (including the already sent ack) so the message is requeued. If you don't use transactions, the message will be lost.